# Why Linux firewall GUI Gufw not in Debian window-key search?

Tags: debian, apt, firewall, ufw

The [guide](https://spreadprivacy.com/linux-privacy-tips-1dc956657357) recommends the Gufw firewall GUI. 
I installed it by `apt`

```
gufw/oldstable,oldstable,now 12.10.0-1 all [installed]
  graphical user interface for ufw
```

Typing ẁindow key + gufw, I cannot see the application. 
Only access is through terminal by `gufw` which is not enough. 
I am thinking why so + how to fix the issue because I am systematically using too little firewall in Linux.

Installation and testing the packages installed

1. Studying the package `masi@masi:$ apt search gufw`

   ```
   Sorting... Done
   Full Text Search... Done
   gufw/oldstable,oldstable,now 12.10.0-1 all [installed]
     graphical user interface for ufw
   ```
2. Installation by method `apt install gufw`
3. Output of `apt show -a gufw` where I am thinking about two packages (17.04 and 12.10) so something conflicting in my system - for some reason `gufw` in terminal starts gufw 12.10

   ```
   Package: gufw
   Source: gui-ufw
   Version: 17.04.1-1.1
   Installed-Size: 3,376 kB
   Maintainer: Python Applications Packaging Team <python-apps-team@lists.alioth.debian.org>
   Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~), ufw (>= 0.34~rc), gir1.2-gtk-3.0, policykit-1, gir1.2-webkit2-4.0, python3-gi, net-tools
   Homepage: http://gufw.org/
   Tag: admin::configuring, implemented-in::python, interface::graphical,
    interface::x11, network::firewall, role::program, scope::utility,
    security::firewall, uitoolkit::gtk, use::configuring, x11::application
   Section: admin
   Priority: optional
   Download-Size: 842 kB
   APT-Sources: http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages

   Package: gufw
   Source: gui-ufw
   Version: 12.10.0-1
   Installed-Size: 1,328 kB
   Maintainer: Devid Antonio Filoni <d.filoni@ubuntu.com>
   Depends: python (>= 2.6.6-7~), ufw (>= 0.31.1), gir1.2-gtk-3.0, gir1.2-polkit-1.0, notify-osd | notification-daemon, policykit-1, python-dbus, python-gobject, gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
   Homepage: https://launchpad.net/gui-ufw
   Tag: admin::configuring, implemented-in::python, interface::x11,
    network::firewall, role::program, scope::utility, security::firewall,
    uitoolkit::gtk, use::configuring, x11::application
   Section: admin
   Priority: optional
   Download-Size: 261 kB
   APT-Manual-Installed: yes
   APT-Sources: http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
   ```
4. Output of `apt-cache policy gufw`

   ```
   gufw:
     Installed: 12.10.0-1
     Candidate: 12.10.0-1
     Version table:
         17.04.1-1.1 0
           200 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
     *** 12.10.0-1 0
           500 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
           500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
5. Output of `dpkg -l gufw`

   ```
    Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
    | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
    |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
    ||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
     +++-===============================-====================-====================-====================================================================
    ii  gufw                            12.10.0-1            all                  graphical user interface for ufw
   ```

I do the following and get `sudo apt -t unstable install gufw`

```
[sudo] password for masi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: gnome-settings-daemon (< 3.19.92) but 3.14.2-3+deb8u1 is to be installed
                             Breaks: mutter (< 3.19.92) but 3.14.4-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (< 1.11.90) but 1.4.4-2.1+deb8u2 is to be installed
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (< 1.7.1) but 1.4.4-2.1+deb8u2 is to be installed
 libgstreamer1.0-0 : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (< 1.11.1) but 1.4.4-2.1+deb8u2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

OS: Debian 8.7
Related bug: [gufw: desktop entry doesn't show up in desktop environments](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=681315)

Comment: Looks like a known bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=681315

Comment: @tripleee Please, see the body. `apt` shows me two packages existing for `gufw`. Typing `gufw` in terminal opens the older version 12.10. What do you think?

Comment: You can only have one version so I guess that's the old one. Nothing here tells us why. Can you show the output of `apt-cache policy gufw` and perhaps for completeness `dpkg -l gufw`?

Comment: @tripleee Please, see the body.

Comment: Did you try `apt -t unstable install gufw`?

Comment: @tripleee Please, see the body.

Comment: Welp, it depends on some packages which appear to be unsafe to upgrade. You can try to force it (and possibly end up upgrading significant portions of your system to `unstable` versions, at your peril) or see if it can somehow be made to work with dependencies ignored. (You probably have older versions of these packages; if you are lucky, they could just happen to work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Stretch was released a couple of weeks ago. Upgrading your entire system to that would seem like the easiest solution to your conundrum.

[The bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=681315) was fixed in the version in Debian Stretch, while the old stable release Jessie was still stuck on a version from almost five years ago.

Comment: Correct answer! I awarded you the bounty. The Gufw is 17.04.1 in Debian 9. The search works as expected. Can you offe an explantation why there is no such problem in Debian 9 version?

Comment: Expanded the answer a bit.